# How to use tensorflow's image classification tutorial for classifying unseen images not in the original training or validation dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

TensorFlow has [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification), which I am able to run.

Then I define this function for using the model:

```
def predict1(model,img):
    img = img.resize((150,150))  
    im = np.array(img)    
    im = im.reshape(-1,np.shape(im)[0],np.shape(im)[1],3)  # resize for 'batch'
    preds = model.predict(im)   # predict
    return preds
```

Then actually use it:

```
img = Image.open('MYIMAGE.jpg')
predict1(model,img)
```

The output is:

```
array([[3415.0505]], dtype=float32)
```

I observe that when a positive number (here 3415.0505) corresponds to one of the categories, a negative number to another one (I realize this after several tries). This is good, I can write a function which returns me a string `'dog'` or `'cat'`, based on the sign of the returned string.

However, I think I am missing the point. What is a better way of actually getting the `'dog'` or `'cat'` prediction?

My method based on the signs would fail if there are numerous categories. I'll use this to classifier to classify into many categories, that's why I would need a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the tutorial you are trying to do,

I have made some modifications to the code in the tutorial since what you are trying to do is a categorical classification, not a binary one.
***For the sake of demonstration***
For the train_gen:

```
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='categorical') // change from binary to categorical
```

For the validation_gen:

```
val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='categorical') // changed from binary to categorical
```

I also updated the output layer since its categorical

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2)  #Changed to 2 since you wanted a multiple output e.g.[ 0.333, -0.1333]
])
```

On the prediction part, I have used  ***tf.math.argmax*** method, It returns the index of the highest value from the prediction.

```
listofLabels = ['dog', 'cat']
x = model.predict(sample_training_images)
labels = tf.math.argmax(x, axis = 1)
print(labels)
for label in labels:
    print(listofLabels[label])
```